# Capistrano 3.0 assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

guys!

I have trouble using capistrano 3.0 on centos vps & rvm

If I add

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

I had an error on both migrations & assets

```
INFO [2b2d81e7] Running bundle exec rake db:migrate on 91.231.85.175
DEBUG [2b2d81e7] Command: cd /home/asiniy/nod_avatars/releases/20131027164508 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate )
cap aborted!
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@nod_avatars/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
```

What's going wrong? It seems that v3.0 is crude and I need to use v2. Ir no?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and trying to figure it out. Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, just use 2.15.3 cap version.

BTW, if you'll find any solution, please write here

Comment: So, have you any solution?

Please plus the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just executed this on my localhost:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

And I found out that it didn't run through because I had a syntax error in my rake file. After fixing that the deployment went through.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire up a rails console on your production server, there is probably an error in your application. If it's the case it will crash

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```